# octave function for ordered/circular perms

Tags: octave

So in octave I can do this

```
octave:3> perms([1 2 3])
ans =

   1   2   3
   2   1   3
   1   3   2
   2   3   1
   3   1   2
   3   2   1
```

but if I want something like `perms` but maintain the order of the input vector (e.g. `[1 2 3]`), as follows

```
1 2 3
3 1 2
2 3 1
```

is there a built in function for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `circshift` can only handle one shift at a time forcing you to loop over it. A vectorized alternative is:

```
octave> x = [4 5 6];
octave> n = numel (x);
octave> idx = mod ((0:(n-1)) .+ ((0:(n-1))'), n) +1;
octave> x(idx)
ans =

   4   5   6
   5   6   4
   6   4   5
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, use [circshift](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/circshift.html).

```
x=[1 2 3];
res=zeros(length(x),length(x));
for ii=1:length(x)
   res(ii,:)=circshift (x', ii-1)
end
```

Comment: this does not work because `x` is a row vector and `circshift` only works on column vectors (to support multiple vectors, one per column)

Comment: @carandraug the solution to that is a single character..... I changed it. I cant try it now, maybe indexes are not right, , but again, that is easily solved.....